# Does the Corpse Crafter feat work on summoned undead?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

The corpse crafter feat from *Libris Mortis p.25* reads:

> Undead you raise or create are tougher than normal.
>
> Benefit: Each undead you raise or create with any necromancy spell gains a +4 enhancement bonus to Strength and +2 hit points per Hit Die.

Summon undead reads:

> This spell functions like summon monster I (PH 285), except that you summon an undead creature.
>
> Summon undead I conjures one of the creatures from the 1st-level list in the accompanying sidebar. You choose which creature to summon, and you can change that choice each time you cast the spell. Summoned undead do not count toward the total Hit Dice of undead that you can control with animate dead or the other command undead abilities. No undead creature you summon can have more Hit Dice than your caster level +1.

Is this undead that is summoned effected by the corpsecrafter feat?

I understand that both Create Undead, and Animate dead would obviously be effected by the feat but was unsure if it effects *summoned* undead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, for two reasons.**

First, *summon undead* is a conjuration (summoning) spell, and Corpse Crafter, as quoted by you, only applies to those undead created or raised via necromancy.  If it's not a necromancy spell, Corpse Crafter doesn't apply.

But let's say that we misread that line and it really means that Corpse Crafter applies to either undead you raise **or** undead you create via necromancy. It still wouldn't apply, because except for the available creatures you can conjure, *summon undead* functions identically to *summon monster.*  And how does *summon monster* get the creatures you call up?

> This spell summons an extraplanar creature (typically an outsider, elemental, or magical beast native to another plane).

When you cast *summon undead,* you have no part in the creation of the undead creatures you summon.  You therefore cannot use Corpse Crafter on them.

Comment: oh my gosh I can’t believe I missed the necromancy spell line.... (facepalm) this is why I come here

Comment: Consider that by letting said player use Corpse Crafter in such a fashion, you're giving them the Augment Summoning feat for free. If you don't see that as disrupting your game's balance (and you'd know better than I would), go for it.  For my part, I'd have them take the second feat or, more likely, pay for a metamagic rod. That way they get what they want but balance is maintained by making them literally pay for the ability.

Comment: Good point, but wilder the main difference be that the augment undead feat applies to all summoned creatures where corpse crafter (if homebrewed in this way) would only apply to one spell?

Comment: If your player is building their character around the undead, the change in versatility will be unimportant. You'd be giving them the only part of Augment Summoning they'd care to use anyway. As mentioned, though, if you don't think it'll break your personal game, feel free- them having fun matters more than the exact number of feats they have.